# OpenLayers .jp2 Support

Tags: openlayers, geoserver, jpeg2000

I am wondering if OpenLayers has support for .jp2 files. I have successfully imported a .jp2 file into geoserver, but when trying to view the layer in openlayers it will not show.

Comment: WMS doesn't use JP2 so OpenLayers doesn't care what format the source data is in. Check the GeoServer log file for issues reading the jp2 file

Comment: Were you ever able to verify if OpenLayers supports JPEG2000 images?

Answer (score 1):

Check your .jp2 layer in Layer Preview in GeoServer UI. If the layer is rendered fine, then check your projection settings, it may be the reason you don't see the layer in OL map.

If you see blank area in Layer Preview, then check the GeoServer log file as @iant has advised.